# Search occurances of numbers in c

Tags: c, search, numbers, integer, strstr

I know how to search for strings in C. I use a for loop then a strstr function to determine if there is any occurrences. But now I have int numbers than i want to search for. I did find couple of examples on internet but all those search for the exact number, which I dont want.
I need to search like "20" and if there is a number "2010" it should display it.

How can I do that in c?

Comment: Search for the number in a string or some other data structure - it is unclear.

Comment: convert the number(s) to a string(s)

Comment: Implement an equivalent of strstr for integers. It can be done with a bit of messing around with integer division and modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing the point... but why not just keep using strstr?

```
int main(){
   char tmpbookyear [] = "this year is 2010";
   char searchCriteria [] = "20";
   char *result;

   if((result = strstr (tmpbookyear, searchCriteria)) != NULL)
       printf ("Returned String: %s\n", result);
   else
       printf("GOT A NULL\n");
}

mike@linux-4puc:~> gcc test.c
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
Returned String: 2010
```

`I need to search like "20" and if there is a number "2010" it should display it.`
That's what you want it to do right?

**EDIT:**

```
char year[] = "2012"; 
char search[] = "2";
if(strstr(year, search) != NULL) 
    { printf("result is %s\n",strstr(year, search)); }

mike@linux-4puc:~> gcc test.c
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
result is 2012
```

Comment: if(strstr(tmpbookyear, searchCriteria) != NULL) {
// SHow results
}
is this correct because i dont get any results ?

Comment: You are using it correctly, are you sure of your input strings? I updated my example to use the code you just posted here. Is this not working for you? Maybe show some of your code that isn't working.

Comment: char year[] = "2012";
char search[] = "2";
if(strstr(year, search) != NULL) {

// Show user the results when found

// Results
 counter++; // Count up
}

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yup, works for me (see edit). That code isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank you. Your code is right, I think there is something else in my code blocking .

Answer (score 1):

Scan through the string character by character, until you find a digit (`isdigit()` returns non-zero). Then convert the string at that location to unsigned long with `strtoul()`. Do the comparison, and then use the end-of-conversion pointer return from `strtoul()` to know where to continue scanning.

Comment: I know how to convert to integer, it is the comparison that I do not know how to do.